# How to kill chrome's GPU process from cmd line?

Tags: google-chrome, gpu, kill

[I'm on OSX but shouldn't be relevant]
oftentimes, with many chrome tabs open, chrome will freeze and not serve any page. What seems to reliably work in this case is to go to:
More Tools > Task Manager -> select 'GPU Process' -> click End Process.
(doesn't require killing chrome, that process will auto-restart)
However this is time consuming and sometimes doesn't work in case chrome is really unresponsive.
also, ps auwx|grep GPU doesn't return anything relevant, so not sure how to find that process from cmd line.

How would one do that?

Comment: Questions on OSX should be asked on [unix.se] or [apple.se].

Comment: it wasn't specific to OSX, it's also valid on ubuntu; @dsstorefile1 's answer was what I was searching for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right idea with the `ps` command. Try `pgrep -f type=gpu-process` instead to get the PID or `pkill -f type=gpu-process` to kill. You can do something similar with `ps` and `grep` if `pgrep` isn't available on macOS.

The underlying problem making Chrome freeze is worth investigating sometime, however.

Comment: due to the fact that some other processes may contain string `type=gpu-process` (for example, `steamwebhelper`) you could add `chrome.*` to the search pattern and the full commands will become respectively `pgrep -f chrome.*type=gpu-process` and `pkill -f chrome.*type=gpu-process`